# How buffer/delay incoming HTTP request until down backend wakes up?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, proxy, buffer, delay

https://companyA.acme.org/custom/api/endpoint1 is hosted on a dedicated ec2 instance
https://companyB.acme.org/another/custom/apiendpoint is hosted on a dedicated ec2 instance

(both ec2 instance are using the same core app, each customer can customize the catalog of API endpoints)

Most of the time those ec2 instances are idle, so we secretly want to stop them, but we don't want the customer to care about the instance being up or not.
We can accept a 2 sec delay on response timing when instance needs to be wake up before answering the customer API call

My idea is to intercept all incoming HTTP request and buffer them before routing + forwarding.
I need a delay to be able to check if a backend matching the subdomain is up or not and wake it up if it is down.

Anyone knows any existing proxy / load balancing solution able to buffer / queue HTTP requests, then allows to do some custom magic (in order to launch the right ec2 instance), then forward the request based on Origin/Referer ?

(the answer being probably every existing proxy for the last part )

I was thinking about the following:

- NGINX in front of everyone (point all route53 subdomains to this NGINX)
- Catch AWS event when someone is calling https://companyA.acme.com/custom/api/endpoint2
- Trigger AWS lambda that will starts corresponding ec2 host

But I am not sure on how NGINX will handle the request buffering / forwarding while I start the ec2 host.

*Bonus question : how not to waste any time forwarding the request in case the backend is already up ?*

Comment: Is AWS Lambda an option for you? If so, you can forgo the dedicated EC2 instances in favor of Amazon API Gateway and AWS Lambda. Then, you won't have to roll your own solution, simultaneously reducing your development costs and infrastructure costs.

Comment: The app is allowing customer to define his own API endpoints. Not sure API gateway can fit then. Anyway Lambda is not really an option for now regarding the existing core app

Comment: Yes, you can define APIs programmatically with API Gateway ([Amazon API Gateway Version 2 API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigatewayv2/latest/api-reference/api-reference.html)). Deploying your multi-tenant application to AWS Lambda is an option you should consider.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I ll submit this design idea to dev team, in the meantime I ll keep try to figure out a solution with the constraints and design they gave me